# Reinstalling Ubuntu over Ubuntu

Tags: reinstalling

I'm having problems with the installation, the following message displays when it starts to install:
"/usr/lib/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_components/nmwidget.py:131 : Warning: Source ID 48711 was not found when attempting to remove it Glib.source_remove(self.rows_changed_id)"